# Is it possible to asynchronously enumerate over chunks of file bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, file, asynchronous, async-await

What I'm trying to do is like

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Read zip file into chunks of bytes of largest size possible
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream"></param>
    /// <returns>Enumeration of byte arrays</returns>
    private static async Task<IEnumerable<byte[]>> ChunkStreamBytes(FileStream stream)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task<byte[]>>();
        for (long bytesRemaining = stream.Length; bytesRemaining > 0;)
        {
            int chunkSize = (int)Math.Min(bytesRemaining, int.MaxValue);
            byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkSize];
            bytesRemaining -= await stream.ReadAsync(chunk, 0, chunk.Length);
            yield return chunk;
        }
    }
```

but I get the error

> The body of ... cannot be an iterator block because
>   Task> is not an iterator interface type

I thought of trying `await Task.WaitAll(...)` where each task is reading a chunk, but I'm not sure if the tasks can run out of order and screw up the file I'm trying to construct. I need to use `async`-`await` pattern because of the context. Any ideas on the proper solution?

Comment: [Async Streams](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/async-streams.md) is, I believe, currently suggested for possible inclusion in C# 8.0: "C# has support for iterator methods and async methods, but no support for a method that is both an iterator and an async method.."

Comment: This may be supported in C# 8, for now you can try the Reactive extensions to do async streams.

Answer (score 2):

The `IEnumerable<T>` / `IEnumerator<T>` API (including the duck-typed equivalent) is inherently synchronous; you cannot make it `async` trivially, because it essentially unpacks into a `bool MoveNext()` and `T Current {get;}` pair - neither of which is `async`. There is much discussion over an `async` enumerable pattern soon, but: not today.